# Joining two CSV files in Bash is not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, join

I have the following files:
**file1.csv**

```
Name,Age,Roll
Anu,21,1
Subi,18,2
Blah,10,3
```

**file2.csv**

```
Fruit,Color,Roll
Mango,Orange,1
Mango,Blue,1
Apple,Black,3
```

I want to join the two files in such a way that this is my result:

```
Name,Age,Roll,Fruit,Color
Anu,21,1,Mango,Orange
Anu,21,1,Mango,Blue
Subi,18,2,,
Blah,10,3,Apple,Black
```

I ran the following command:
 `join -t, -a1 -13 -23 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2 file1.csv file2.csv`

This was the output I got:

```
,Fruit,Colorl 
,Mango,Orange
,Mango,Blue
,,bi,18,2
Blah,10,3,Apple,Black
```

This wasn't the output I required (actually, I didn't even understand how this output came to be), so I tried again: 
`join -t, -a1 -13 -23 hi.csv hi2.csv`

The output I got:

```
,Name,Age,Fruit,Color
,Anu,21,Mango,Orange
,Anu,21,Mango,Blue
Subi,18,2
3,Blah,10,Apple,Black
```

At this point I'm clueless. I have tried `join` on normal `.txt` files and they have worked perfectly. I have also referred to various other solutions for similar questions on stackoverflow and none worked. Please help.

Note: I am using a Mac.

Comment: Does the file contain carriage returns? Run `dos2unix file` or `sed $'s/\r//' file` and your first command should work as expected.

Comment: @123 Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems that **[123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123)** gave the essential hint.

To check this out I prepared your sample files in

- Unix style: line-endings `\n` (`file1.csv`, `file2.csv`)
- Mac style: line-endings `\r` (`macfile1.csv`, `macfile2.csv`)
- DOS/Windows style: line-endings `\r\n` (`dosfile1.csv`, `dosfile2.csv`).

My test session (in bash on cygwin):

```
$ join -t, -a1 -13 -23 file1.csv file2.csv
Roll,Name,Age,Fruit,Color
1,Anu,21,Mango,Orange
1,Anu,21,Mango,Blue
2,Subi,18
3,Blah,10,Apple,Black

$ hexdump -c file1.csv 
0000000   N   a   m   e   ,   A   g   e   ,   R   o   l   l  \n   A   n
0000010   u   ,   2   1   ,   1  \n   S   u   b   i   ,   1   8   ,   2
0000020  \n   B   l   a   h   ,   1   0   ,   3  \n                    
000002b

$ cat file1.csv | tr "\n" "\r" >macfile1.csv

$ cat file2.csv | tr "\n" "\r" >macfile2.csv

$ hexdump -c macfile1.csv 
0000000   N   a   m   e   ,   A   g   e   ,   R   o   l   l  \r   A   n
0000010   u   ,   2   1   ,   1  \r   S   u   b   i   ,   1   8   ,   2
0000020  \r   B   l   a   h   ,   1   0   ,   3  \r                    
000002b

$ cat file1.csv | sed $'s/$/\r/' >dosfile1.csv

$ cat file2.csv | sed $'s/$/\r/' >dosfile2.csv

$ hexdump -c dosfile1.csv 
0000000   N   a   m   e   ,   A   g   e   ,   R   o   l   l  \r  \n   A
0000010   n   u   ,   2   1   ,   1  \r  \n   S   u   b   i   ,   1   8
0000020   ,   2  \r  \n   B   l   a   h   ,   1   0   ,   3  \r  \n    
000002f

$ join -t, -a1 -13 -23 file1.csv file2.csv
Roll,Name,Age,Fruit,Color
1,Anu,21,Mango,Orange
1,Anu,21,Mango,Blue
2,Subi,18
3,Blah,10,Apple,Black

$ join -t, -a1 -13 -23 macfile1.csv macfile2.csv
Blah,10,3Age,21,1

$ join -t, -a1 -13 -23 dosfile1.csv dosfile2.csv
,Name,Age,Fruit,Color
,Anu,21,Mango,Orange
,Anu,21,Mango,Blue
,Subi,18
,Blah,10,Apple,Black

$
```

...and applying what **[123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123)** recommended:

```
$ cat dosfile1.csv | sed $'s/\r//' >dosfile1.fixed.csv

$ cat dosfile2.csv | sed $'s/\r//' >dosfile2.fixed.csv

$ join -t, -a1 -13 -23 dosfile1.fixed.csv dosfile2.fixed.csv
Roll,Name,Age,Fruit,Color
1,Anu,21,Mango,Orange
1,Anu,21,Mango,Blue
2,Subi,18
3,Blah,10,Apple,Black

$
```

...the expected output can be achieved.

Hopefully, it will work the same way on the Mac.